# How to run script as pytest test

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Suppose I have a test expressed as a simple script with `assert`-statements (see background for why), e.g

```
import foo
assert foo(3) == 4
```

How would I include this script in my pytest test suite -- in a nice way?

I have tried two working but less-than-nice approaches:

One approach is to name the script like a test, but this makes the whole pytest discovery fail when the test fails.

My current approach is to import the script from within a test function:

```
def test_notebooks():
    notebook_folder = Path(__file__).parent / 'notebooks'
    for notebook in notebook_folder.glob('*.py'):
        import_module(f'{notebook_folder.name}.{notebook.stem}')
```

This works, but the scripts are not reported individually and test failures have a long and winding stack trace:

```
__________________________________________________ test_notebooks ___________________________________________________

    def test_notebooks():
        notebook_folder = Path(__file__).parent / 'notebooks'
        for notebook in notebook_folder.glob('*.py'):
>           import_module(f'{notebook_folder.name}.{notebook.stem}')

test_notebooks.py:7:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
envs\anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006: in _gcd_import
... (9 lines removed)...
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: in _call_with_frames_removed
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

>   assert False
E   AssertionError

notebooks\notebook_2.py:1: AssertionError
```

### Background

The reason I have test in script files is that they are really Jupyter notebooks saved as `.py`-files with markup by the excellent [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) plugin.

These notebooks are converted to html for documentation, can be used interactively for learning the system, and serve as cheap functional tests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Executing scripts in a test function

There's nothing wrong with calling the scripts from a test function, so your approach is perfectly fine. However, I would use parametrization instead of running the scripts in a for loop; this way you get the test executed nicely once per script. If you don't like the long tracebacks, you can cut them in a custom [`pytest_exception_interact`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact) hookimpl. Example:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    excinfo = call.excinfo
    if 'script' in node.funcargs:
        excinfo.traceback = excinfo.traceback.cut(path=node.funcargs['script'])
    report.longrepr = node.repr_failure(excinfo)
```

Parametrized tests:

```
# test_spam.py

import pathlib
import runpy
import pytest

scripts = pathlib.Path(__file__, '..', 'scripts').resolve().glob('*.py')


@pytest.mark.parametrize('script', scripts)
def test_script_execution(script):
    runpy.run_path(script)
```

Test execution yields (for testing, I have created simple scripts with single lines like `assert False` or `1 / 0`:

```
$ pytest -v
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.6.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /home/hoefling/projects/.venvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-56807698
plugins: mock-1.10.4, cov-2.7.1, forked-1.0.2, xdist-1.28.0, django-3.4.8
collected 3 items                                                                                  

test_spam.py::test_script_execution[script0] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_script_execution[script1] FAILED
test_spam.py::test_script_execution[script2] FAILED

============================================= FAILURES =============================================
____________________________________ test_script_runpy[script1] ____________________________________

>   assert False
E   AssertionError

scripts/script_3.py:1: AssertionError
____________________________________ test_script_runpy[script2] ____________________________________

>   1 / 0
E   ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

scripts/script_2.py:1: ZeroDivisionError
================================ 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.07 seconds ================================
```

#### Custom test protocol

If you don't like the above solution, another thing I can think of is to implement your own test collection & execution protocol. Example:

```
# conftest.py

import pathlib
import runpy
import pytest


def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    p = pathlib.Path(str(path))
    if p.suffix == '.py' and p.parent.name == 'scripts':
        return Script(path, parent)


class Script(pytest.File):
    def collect(self):
        yield ScriptItem(self.name, self)


class ScriptItem(pytest.Item):
    def runtest(self):
        runpy.run_path(self.fspath)

    def repr_failure(self, excinfo):
        excinfo.traceback = excinfo.traceback.cut(path=self.fspath)
        return super().repr_failure(excinfo)
```

This will collect every `.py` file in `scripts` directory, wrap each script in a test case and invoke `runpy` on test execution. The execution log will look pretty much the same, just the tests named differently.

Comment: Excellent! My plan was to research along the lines of the custom test protocol, but the combination of parametrization and `runpy` over `import` is much less opaque and exactly what I need. Have edited the question to add your point that my current solution doesn't tag scripts individually.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: For greater readability, you can add `ids=lambda script: script.stem` to the call to `pytest.mark.parametrize` in order to assign the script file names as test id's

Comment: For this `ids` setting to work, you need to make examples a list, not a generator object. i.e., `examples = list(pathlib.Path...glob('py'))`