# Can pytest suppress tracebacks in 3rd party code?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm writing tests using pytest, on an application that uses sqlalchemy. When the application does something wrong that triggers an uncaught exception deep in the sqlalchemy call stack, we get an enormous stack trace, the majority of which isn't helpful for understanding the cause of the failure.

Is it possible to configure pytest to filter off parts of the stack trace that are in specific 3rd party modules? That way, when an exception is raised, the pytest report would draw our attention more directly to the parts of *our* code that cause the failure.

Comment: You can implement the `pytest_exception_interact` where you can cut or filter the `excinfo.traceback`.

Comment: @hoefling - How does `pytest_exception_interact()` modify the traceback that gets displayed? As far as I can tell, it can only inspect the traceback, but you'll still get the full output from pytest.

Comment: There is an open issue on the pytest tracker about [adding a hook to filter traceback output](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/283), and another about [highlighting user code vs. framework code in traceback output](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/522).

Comment: @NickChammas by setting `excinfo.traceback` to new traceback. I gave an example of cutting the traceback object [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813896/2650249).

Comment: Yes, it can do this trivially. Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57730488/2312300